# How to find out where style attribute is added in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am currently working on a website where various scripts are modifying the DOM (both through click/hover type events, and also on page load), changing heights/widths of elements etc and am trying to find out which scripts are affecting which elements. For example, `height: 9px` is being added to the `<span>` element below, and I need to know what script is doing this (currently using Chrome Dev Tools, though if another browser can accomplish this task better, I'm open):

```
<span data-id="m_left_fitting_finish_filter" class="sidebar__filterBlock-title" style="height: 9px;">
```

Tried selecting `Break on` > `Attributes modifications` and reloading the page, though this didn't seem to do anything - does this only work for Class/ID changes?

Comment: Firebug 2.0.3 for firefox...

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya Please can you provide instructions for achieving this in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Open `console` , select `Elements` tab, at right panel select `Styles` tab. Should list file which loaded `css`. Can move back to left panel , select `Sources` tab; can then select a script from far left panel, highlight entire script, if necessary, right click, select `Add to Watch`. Alternatively, could copy entire script, by selecting `script` in left panel , right click , select `Add Folder to Workspace`, evaluate in text editor for `height` property being set.

Answer (score 0):

That is a great question, I hope that video can be of help also (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vh-lZR2z_Lw&feature=youtu.be) , but in easy steps for you to reproduce is this:

- open inspector
- go to 'profiles' tab
- be ready for start / stop button to record all scripts on your actions
- do the actual action (mouseover, click, tap.. etc)
- examine the profilers 'spikes', ignore some framework initiated one.. (there is a way for you to blacklist some scripts like jQuery or such but you can Google this I think :)

hth!

Comment: Thanks for the response, though in my particular case, the style attribute appears on load, rather than triggered by an action, making things a bit tricky to find, unless there is another way around?

Comment: You can for sure press "start" record btn, refresh the page, and then "stop" to see page load events

Comment: There are 100's in that list in my particular case (working on a large Magento website with various modules installed), and would still take a very long time. Currently investigating what other browsers have to offer.